# The Appian way to add a derived field to a common data type on the fly?

Tags: arrays, concatenation, appian

Assume I have an [Appian common data type (CDT)](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/cdt_design_guidance.html) called `myTask` which contains multiple fields `taskName`, `taskQuarter`, `taskYear`, `taskId` saved in a local variable (of an [Interface](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/interface_object.html)) which looks for instance as follows

```
+ data (List of dictionary)
  + (Dictionary)
    - taskName:    "Plant trees." (Text)
    - taskQuarter: 1              (Number (Integer))
    - taskYear:    2020           (Number (Integer))
    - taskId:      0              (Number (Integer))
  + (Dictionary)
    - taskName:    "Cut leaves." (Text)
    - taskQuarter: 2              (Number (Integer))
    - taskYear:    2020           (Number (Integer))
    - taskId:      1              (Number (Integer))
```

In the local scope (of the interface), I would like to have an additional field for all records called `taskLongName` which would be the following concatenation (in pseudocode):

```
taskLongName = taskName + " " + taskYear + " Q" + taskQuarter
```

How do I do that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be rather simple: Assuming that you have an expression rule `myGetAllTasks()` defined, you could put the initial list of dictionaries into `local!allTasks`. Next, we use [Appian's `a!forEach()`](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/fnc_looping_a_foreach.html) function:

```
a!localVariables(
local!allTasks: rule!myGetAllTasks().data, 
local!taskLongNames: 
  a!foreach(
    items: local!allTasks,
    expression: concat(
      fv!item.taskName, " for ",
      fv!item.processYear, " Q",
      fv!item.processQuarter
    )
  ),
  ... <-- Here comes the configuration (code) defining the actual interface
)
```